# How to handle keyboard actions or add functions in keyboard TextInputAction in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-softkeyboard

I have simple TextField below. I wanted to call my search function when I pressed the TextInputAction button of the SofInput Keyboard.

```
TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Number'),
),

// Example only
void myCustomFunction() => SearchNumber();
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you press that button the `onSumbitted` method get called so you can do this:

```
onSubmitted: (val) => searchNumber(),
```